# Value error in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

Hey guys can someone help me out with my code please, can't find out what to change.Please help its very difficult for me since i am new to using deep-learning. I know that the shape is the problem but I do not know what to change it to or how to in keras

```
import csv
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

lines=[]
with open('/home/charan/Desktop/Car/Term1/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3/data/data/driving_log.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    #read = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    for line in reader:
       lines.append(line)
images = []
measurements = []
for line in lines:
    source_path = line[0]
    #print(source_path)
    filename = source_path.split('/')[-1]
    current_path = "/home/charan/Desktop/Car/Term1/CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3/output/IMG/" + filename
    image = cv2.imread(current_path)
    img = images.append(image)
    measurement = float(line[3])
    measurements.append(measurement)
X_train = np.array(images) 
y_train = np.array(measurements)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(160,320,3)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, nb_epoch=7)
model.save('model.h5')
```

I am getting a Value error as such:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected lambda_input_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8037, 1)
```

In the line

```
---> 50 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Could you print out the first row of `X_train`?

Comment: You're missing a Z_train, or third axis. It tells you that the function expects the 3 parameters, but you have passed 2.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko If I print the X_train i am getting it as None

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I was able to print the whole of the images

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Thanks your pointer helped me decode the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your images size. 
If not all the images are the same size the shape of X_train won't match the input of your model.

Try resizing all of your images to the same size like this:

change this:

```
image = cv2.imread(current_path)
```

into:

```
image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(current_path),(256,256))
```

and this:

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(160,320,3)))
```

into:

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(256,256,3)))
```

Comment: The image is same as that of the flatten but it is showing value error because of y_train This is the error I am getting`ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected flatten_input_4 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (8037, 1)`. I used the X_train[1].shape to confirm the shape

Comment: I managed to reproduce your problem in two ways:
The first is if I add error in one of the images names in the imread.
The second is by having images with different sizes (you need one picture with different size to cause the problem and this is why checking the  X_train[1].shape doesn't really tell you if there is a problem or not).

Comment: The images are returning the correct shape when i call each element of the X_train but when i plainly print out the shape of X_train it is showing it as an array of (8037,1). Is there some problem with numpy array???

Comment: There was an error with the path to X_train. I removed it and refreshed the path. It worked

Comment: Ive got the answer there was a problem linking the code to the images folder. I replaced it and it worked like a charm thanks guys